# Interoperability of SIP/H.323/IAX2

Tags: interop, sip, voip, h.323

I am curious to know if interoperability exists between those three protocols. Like if a call originated from a SIP protocol can go through a H.323 protocol? An article or book link about this topic will be much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIP, H.323 and IAX2 are all different protocols and are not directly interoperable.  That is, you cannot connect a SIP phone to an H.323 device and make a call.

The problems these protocols solve are all similar (e.g. Make a voice or video call).  Protocol converters and other devices (like gateways) are available and can do the conversion.

You may also have to transcode the audio and video data from one codec to another, but you may also have to do that on a SIP-SIP or H.323-H.323 call.

Many PBXes and SoftSwitches support both SIP and H.323:  asterisk supports all 3 (SIP, H.323 and IAX2).